# background html CHM

Tags: c#, html, css, vb.net

I finished the help of my system in html with 'html workshop'

I'm having a problem with the background of the pages.

I am using a background image in my html pages and in editor works correctly but when I compile the chm with html workshop, all styles in html pages see but the background disappear and set into blank.

can I change the background in pages on chm or not?

thanks

Comment: Upload your image somewhere and set the URL as the source, seems easier :)

Comment: @Tico I have the background image in a directory. This is the problem? I try upload the image somewhere and say to you the results

Comment: Probably! Referencing from local directories always smells like trouble!

Comment: @Tico yes, it works.. what hosting is recommended for images? also I like that the image is in a special directory, its possible?

Comment: Not sure, man. Create a Google Drive, SkyDrive, Dropbox account and leave it there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly include your background image in compiled CHM. If an image is referenced with `<img>` tag, HHW will include it automatically. But if you use an image with CSS, you need to do it yourself:

1. In HHW, go to Project tab and press Add/Remove topic files button.
2. Press Add... button.
3. Type * in the File name field so that you can see all files, including images.
4. Select your background image file.
5. Save the project and compile. The background should be visible now.

Tip. If you have many images to include, you can use wildcards. Close HHW and open .hhp file in a text editor. Find the [FILES] section and add something like:
MyImagesFolder\*.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Upload your image somewhere and set the URL as the source, seems easier.

Create a Google Drive, SkyDrive, Dropbox account and leave it there!

Comment: Since OP is OK, I'm leaving as an answer